# Child Div Sticking out of parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the character div inside of the game div but its sticking out. I am trying to make a game and I am not too experienced in css and would appreciate any suggestions and feedback.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#game {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  animation: block 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px;
  }
}

#character {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="block"></div>
  <div id="character"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/skltnboss/Ljb845h3

Comment: `#block` is taking all the height, therefore `#character` sits below it, You might want to look into `position:absolute` It's optimal for this sort of thing

Comment: Do you want the character to have position absolute and be positioned within the game element? If so give game position: relative as well and position character top: 0 and left: 0.

Comment: Do you want #character to place inside #game as the finish line, and eventually, #block to place over it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly understand by stick, but if you want it not to exceed the boundaries of the #game then make the left property not to be less than 0:

```
#character: {
   left: 0;
}
```

If you want it to move to the left and disappear as it does now, but without going out of the #game then specify the overflow property of the #game to be hidden:

```
#game {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```